# Defining a map on a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

In defining a map (homomorphism or not) on a group $G$, must one check well-definedness for both positive and negative elements *separately*? Or are there circumstances which allow one to specify the rule for a generic element of $G$ (of course not counting the trivial constant maps)?

EDIT: My question is phrased rather poorly. Let's take an example. Suppose I want to extend $2^{-}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Can I just say that $2^{-}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by the same rule that specifies the map from $\mathbb{N}$? Of course not: I have to specify the rule separately for the negative elements (am I always bound to send $-n$ to $1/2^{n}$?). I just wanted to know whether there exist general considerations that demand for a map to be specified in this manner.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive and negative elements"?

Comment: I mean elements and their inverses: e.g., $5$ and $-5$ for integers

Comment: Why not just prove it for **all** elements without restriction? Can you please give an example where you are unsure?

Comment: Is it always possible to define a map from a group by specifying the rule for all elements? (e.g. extending multiplication by $4$ from natural to integers)

Comment: What is wrong with $n \mapsto 4n$ defined for all integers?

Comment: If you **define** a map, then all is fine. You define a map $f\colon G\to X$ by specifying a specific element $f(g)\in X$ for every possible $g\in G$.

Comment: @Somos But do you mean to say that the map $2^{-}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (base 2 exponential function) is automatically specified when we specify $2^{-}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$?

Comment: You must define it for all elements of the group. As far as “well-definedness”, see [these comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60781/symmetric-groups-on-sets-with-the-same-number-of-elements-are-isomorphic/60788#60788)

Comment: If you don't make any assumption on the map there is no way to extend automatically a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand if your map is a monoid morphism into a group, then it extends uniquely to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your clarified question is something like this. Suppose we have
a group $G$ which has a set of free generators $F$ and a group $H$. Then **any** function $\,f:F\to H$ can be extended uniquely in the natural way to a **homomorphism** function $\,f^*:G\to H$ so that they agree on $F$ by the universal property of the free group. However, if we do **not** require the function to be a homomorphism, then we need to define it on the **entire** domain because that is what it means to define a function. Thus,
$\,2^{-}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\,$

Please refer to the Wikipedia article [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) for more details about this.

However, what might be confusing you is a common **abuse of notation**.
That is, by using an expression of the form $\, 2^n \,$ **without**
specifying the domain of definition. In this and similar cases, the
expression does **not** define a function because the domain is not
explicitly given. A function requires **both** a domain and a rule giving
values of the function in its domain. In other words $\,f(x):=2^x\,$
does not define a function unless its domain is explicitly (or much more
likely implicitly) given.
Thus, $\,2^{-}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \,$ is okay
since the domain is explicitly given and it is implictly assumed that
$\,2^x\,$ has a well defined meaning.