# How to prove a bijection is "well defined" and "surjective" properly? (with an example)

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Here is an example of my proof of a question:

Prove that $\mathbb{C}^*$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices of the form.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
-b&a\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here is my proof:

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}^*=\{z=a-bi; a^2+b^2\neq 0\}$
and
$g\in G=\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
-b&a\\
\end{pmatrix}
;a^2+b^2\neq 0\}
$.
Suppose there exists a mapping $\phi$, such that $\phi:\mathbb{C}^*\to G$ by $\phi: z\mapsto g$. This relation is well defined and it is onto because for every $z=a-bi\in\mathbb{C}^*$, we have the representation $\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
-b&a\\
\end{pmatrix}\in G$. It is also injective because when $\phi(z_1)=\phi(z_2)$, we have
$$ \phi(z_1)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\
-b_1&a_1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\phi(z_2)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2&b_2\\
-b_2&a_2\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So $a_1-b_1i=a_2-b_2i$, in another word $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$, therefore $z_1=z_2$.

Then to show that $\phi$ preserves the group operation, observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\phi(z_1z_2)&=\phi((a_1a_2-b_1b_2)-(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)i)\\
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1a_2-b_1b_2&a_2b_1+a_1b_2\\
-(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)&a_1a_2-b_1b_2\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\
-b_1&a_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2&b_2\\
-b_2&a_2
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
&=\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2).
\end{split}
\end{align}
$$
Hence $\phi$ is isomorphism and $\mathbb{C}^*\cong G$.

This is certainly not a hard question. And I would like you guys to comment on my proof and tell me if this is rigorous enough because, in my opinion, I found there is something unsatisfactory to me. For example, I want to explain why it is "well-defined" but I don't really know what "well-defined" means while both my textbook and my Prof always begin with "this function /map is well-defined" in their proof of bijection but rarely stating the reason. So I wonder if it is just a 'meaningless' convention for the proof of a bijection or there is something deeper underneath it?

My second unsatisfactions with this proof is about "onto/surjective". At this stage, I think I know what it means mathematically, which simply is that for every $y$ on the range we can find a unique $x$ on the domain that is mapped to it. However, when this statement is included in a proof, I immediately feel it lacks something so that as you can see from my example that I don't really prove it but instead restating or paraphrasing my previous definition of the map. This is also something that happened a lot during my reading of the textbook and my Prof's lecture. It sounds like as long as $\phi$ is "well-defined", then it must be "onto". I just want to ask is there anything I can do with the language here or actually, there is a brief proof for onto so that in any circumstances I can boost this sentence to a more convincing level?

These two questions have been around me from the beginning, and I know I haven't studied the very core part of this subject and probably never, but I just want to throw out these questions and see how you guys react to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your $G$ isn't quite right because you've allowed the zero matrix to be in it, for example.

Comment: Your function is in fact clearly well-defined because the representation $a+bi$ of a complex number is unique with respect to $a$, $b$.

Comment: So what exactly means well-defined?

Comment: Your explanation of why the function is onto is incorrect.  You need to prove that for every element $g\in G$, there exists an element $z\in C^*$ such that $\phi(z) = g$.  And as @Randall commented, we must have $a, b$ not both equal to zero.

Comment: @amWhy How to do it exactly? I know in some cases I can prove onto with algebra. For example, to prove $U(5)$ and $U(10)$ are isomorphic, I can list out the mapping and show that it is one to one and onto.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Abstract Algebra Theory and Application by Thomas W. Judson.

Comment: @Randall , is that correct if I state that either $b=0$, when $a\in\mathbb{R}/{0}$ and vice versa.

Comment: No, because you can let ONE of them be zero and it's okay.

Comment: Why not just say $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ since that's the determinant?

Comment: @Randall Yes you are right I have edited it already.

Comment: I would object to your "Suppose there exists a mapping..." $g$ and $z$ are not determined; you have not even told us that they correspond to the same choice of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. You have to say so explicitly! After all, your second set could just as well be described as the set of all matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{ll}t&s\\-s&t\end{array}\right)$, since $a$ and $b$ are dummy variables in the definition. Then how do you "relate" $z$ with $g$? Also, if you are **assuming** that you have a map/function $\phi$, then talking about it being "well-defined" is nonsense. It's a function!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin About $a$, $b$, they are not chosen by me but instead given by the textbook which this question belong to. And plus, why you called $a$, $b$ are dummy variables, is there any bad about them? What do you think will be a better way to express $g$ and $z$ in this case? since I don't know a lot about formatting so I can't avoid to make some mistake sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: "Dummy variables" means that the specific name you use does not affect the object described. Just like $\int_0^1 x\,dx$ is the same object as $\int_0^1 t\,dt$ and as $\int_0^1 y\,dy$; they all represent the number $\frac{1}{2}$, and whether you use $x$, $y$, or $t$ as the variable name is irrelevant. In the same way, if I describe a set a $\{x\mid x\text{ is an integer between }1\text{ and }10\}$, I am describing the same set as $\{y\mid y\text{ is an integer between }1\text{ and }10\}$.

Comment: Following up the first comment of @ArturoMagidin, by writing "Suppose there exists a mapping..." you have violated the required logic of the proof. You are required to prove the *existence* of the mapping $\phi$. To do that you must write down its formula, and then prove that the formula you wrote satisfies the required properties. So what you should have in that spot of the proof is something like "Let $\phi : \mathbb C^* \to G$ be the mapping given by the formula...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a detailed commentary...

> Let $z\in\mathbb{C}^*=\{z=a-bi; a^2+b^2\neq 0\}$
> and
> $g\in G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
> a&b\\
> -b&a\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> ;a^2+b^2\neq 0\right\}
> $.
> Suppose there exists a mapping $\phi$, such that $\phi:\mathbb{C}^*\to G$ by $\phi: z\mapsto g$.

Okay; first, you are supposed to *produce* a bijection that is a group isomorphism. So saying "Suppose there exists a mapping $\phi$" doesn't do anything. You are saying "Suppose we have a function between the two sets". If you define it, then I don't have to suppose anything. If you don't define it, then you aren't doing anything except asking me to make an unwarranted assumption. So what you are trying to do is **define** a function, not "suppose that a function exists".

Second: the description of $\mathbb{C}^*$ says that it consists of **all** elements of the form $a-bi$ with $a^2+b^2\neq 0$ (note, it should specify that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers). *Any* such number. The description of $G$ says that it consists of all matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
a & b\\
-b & a\end{array}\right),$$
with $a^2+b^2\neq 0$ (again, the description is missing that $a$ and $b$ are expected to be real numbers).

But you can describe them with any letters; if I tell you that $G$ consists of all matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\xi & \theta\\
-\theta & \xi\end{array}\right)$$
where $\theta,\xi$ are real numbers such that $\theta^2+\xi^2\neq 0$, then I've described the exact same set of matrices. I don't have to use $a$ and $b$: they are "dummy variables": their names don't matter in the description. You can change them at will to any two symbols that are distinct from each other and not being used elsewhere, and you will describe the exact same collection of objects. These letters are not fixed, so you should not assume them to be fixed.

You tell me: let $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$, and let $g\in G$. I can say: okay, I'm going to take $z=3-7i$; that's an element of $\mathbb{C}^*$. And I'm going to take $g$ to be the matrix
$$g = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
\pi & \sqrt{2}\\
-\sqrt{2} &\pi\end{array}\right).$$
That's a perfectly fine element of $G$.

*Then* you tell me that $\phi$ will send *this* $z$ to *this* $g$; well... okay... but what does it do with any other element of $\mathbb{C}^*$? And why am I sending **this** $z$ to **this** $g$? Note that you did not put *any* conditions on the $z$ and $g$ that I was supposed to pick, nor did you tell me that you were defining something for *all* $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$. The *only* thing you told me to do was to take an element of $\mathbb{C}^*$ and an element of $G$, and I did so.

Note that $a$ and $b$ in the descriptions of $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $G$ are not fixed numbers; they are free variables that can take any value as long as they satisfy the given conditions (both real, not both zero). Unless you tell me what they are, you aren't telling me what the function is.

So presumably you meant to do something like the following:

> > **Define** $\phi\colon\mathbb{C}^*\to G$ as follows: given $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$, write $z=a-bi$; then let $\phi(z)$ be the element
> > $$\phi(z)=g=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
> > a&b\\
> > -b&a
> > \end{array}\right).$$
> > Note that this $g$ indeed lies in $G$; and that since the expression of a complex number in the form $a-bi$ with $a$ and $b$ reals is unique, this completely determines the value of $\phi$ at $z$.

Moving on:

> This relation is well defined and it is onto because for every $z=a-bi\in\mathbb{C}^*$, we have the representation $\begin{pmatrix}
> a&b\\
> -b&a\\
> \end{pmatrix}\in G$.

It's not a "representation". What you mean is that the object you (tried but did not in fact) defined to be the value of $\phi$ at $z$ is indeed an object of $G$, which you should phrase as I did above or in some similar way. Note that here we are *defining* a function, so we need to check this. In your original phrasing, you instructed me to *assume* I had a function, so checking if it is a function is a waste. If you tell me "Assume you have a dime; now let's verify that you would then indeed have a dime", I would say "Well, if we are *assuming* I have a dime, why do we need to check that this would mean I have a dime? You just told me I should assume I do."

Moreover, you are doing the wrong thing to show it is onto/surjective. To show it is surjective, you must show that for every element $g\in G$ there is an element $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $\phi(z)=g$. But you start by picking an element of $\mathbb{C}^*$, and showing me that $\phi(z)$ lies in $G$. This only shows that you have correctly identified a domain and a codomain, *not* that $\phi$ is surjective. So your argument to show $\phi$ is surjective is incorrect.

> It is also injective because when $\phi(z_1)=\phi(z_2)$, we have
> $$ \phi(z_1)=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_1&b_1\\
> -b_1&a_1\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \phi(z_2)=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_2&b_2\\
> -b_2&a_2\\
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
> So $a_1-b_1i=a_2-b_2i$, in another word $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$, therefore $z_1=z_2$.

This is fine, once you correctly define $\phi$.

> Then to show that $\phi$ preserves the group operation, observe that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \begin{split}
> \phi(z_1z_2)&=\phi((a_1a_2-b_1b_2)-(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)i)\\
> \\
> &=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_1a_2-b_1b_2&a_2b_1+a_1b_2\\
> -(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)&a_1a_2-b_1b_2\\
> \end{pmatrix}\\
> \\
> &=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_1&b_1\\
> -b_1&a_1
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_2&b_2\\
> -b_2&a_2
> \end{pmatrix}\\
> \\
> &=\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2).
> \end{split}
> \end{align}
> $$

This is also perfectly fine.

> Hence $\phi$ is isomorphism and $\mathbb{C}^*\cong G$.

*If* you had correctly shown that $\phi$ is onto, then this would indeed follow.

As for "well-defined"... [see the comments the first three paragraphs this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60781/symmetric-groups-on-sets-with-the-same-number-of-elements-are-isomorphic/60788#60788).

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me mistake and paraphrasing my word. So let me digest what you said. First, I state the two sets/groups that I am going tou define $\phi$ being the function that maps

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me mistake and paraphrasing my word. So let me digest what you said. First, I state the sets/groups that I am going to use in this case will be $\mathbb{C}^*$ and the matrix subgroup $G$. Then define $\phi$ being the function that maps from $\mathbb{C}$ to $G$, and then state that I am going to take $z$ from $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $g$ from $G$, so that $\phi$ will map $z$ to $g$ and now this $\phi$ is well defined.  Following up after that, I just need to prove "onto"(correcting my argument), then one to one, finally show that $\phi$ is isomorphsim. Is this correct

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak: To specify $\phi$ you need to tell me how to take a specific element of $z$ to some element of $G$. You aren't doing that; read my proposed wording for how to do it correctly. You do not "state that I am going to take $z$ from $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $g$ from $G$". You take an element of $\mathbb{C}^*$, and you explain how to determine **which** element of $G$ you will map it to. You can give it a name after you decide where to map it, but don't "pick" something from $G$ before you describe how you are defining $\phi$.

Comment: I see what you are saying. So to define a map $\phi:\mathbb{C}^*\to G$, first I state my domain which is $\mathbb{C}^*$ in this case, and then given $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$, define a function such that $\phi(z)=\text{that matrix form}$. This now allows me to define my codomain since all matrices have that form lie in $G$. Hence $\phi$ is mapping $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $G$. Is this order correct?

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak: I wonder if there is some language barrier here: you keep misusing "define". And we aren't communicating effectively. You can say "Define a function $\phi\colon\mathbb{C}^*\to G$ as follows" (that will identify the domain and the intended codomain). Then you say "Given $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$..." and you need to explain how one takes a given element of $z$ and identifies the element of $G$ you will map it to. So you would want to say something like "Given $z\in\mathbb{C}^*$, let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $z=a-bi$; then define $\phi(z)$ to be the matrix `blah`" (cont)

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak (cont), where `blah` somehow uses $a$ and $b$ to describe the matrix you are defining. This matrix will either obviously be in $G$, and there is nothing more to say in terms of this being a function from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $G$; or it will be perhaps not entirely clear depending on your description, in which case you will want to spend some words explaining why, even though it is not obviously in $G$, it actually *is* in $G$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for that. And indeed there is a language barrier since I am not really familiar with how to use the word such as "define", "suppose", "given" and so on in a proof so sometime you will see I overuse a word without caring too much of its meaning.