# Show $S_7$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of all those elements of $S_8$ which leave the number $5$ fixed

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

First of all I don't know how to write with correct notation in this site, sorry about that.

Second, I am a beginner with group theory so I am trying to solve this exercise (Fraleigh).

Until now I have a function that maps a permutation in $S_7$ to $S_8$ like this:

Suppose $\sigma$ , any permutation in $S_7$.

$5$ if $x=5$

$\sigma(x)$ if $\sigma(x)\neq 5$

Here I have the first problem, because I have two cells free: $8$ and the element that is sent to $5$ in $S_7$, so I maps like this:

$\sigma(5)$ if $\sigma(x)=5$

$8$ if $x=8$

So I would appreciate your help in this exercise, I don't know if this function is correct and how to prove if in fact is an isomorphism.

Comment: Hinr. Renumber the elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8\}$ using the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  On this site use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Possibly Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60781/symmetric-groups-on-sets-with-the-same-number-of-elements-are-isomorphic?rq=1

Comment: What if $x=5$ and $\sigma(x)\neq 5$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Let $\tau=(58)$. Then the subgroup in question is $\tau S_7 \tau^{-1} \cong S_7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm sure this has been answered here before but, since I can't find a duplicate, I'll give a CW answer.*

There's nothing special about $7$, $8$, and $5$ here.

> **Theorem:** Let $n\in \Bbb N$ and $m\in\{1,\dots, n+1\}$. Then $S_n$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $H$ of $S_{n+1}$ whose elements fix $m$.

*Proof:* We may assume, by reindexing if necessary, that $m=n+1$.

We have that

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: H&\to S_n,\\
\sigma &\mapsto \sigma_H,
\end{align}$$

where

$$\sigma_H(x)=\sigma(x)$$

for $x\in \{1,\dots, n\}$, is an isomorphism, since it is clearly a bijection and

$$\begin{align}
(\varphi(\tau\rho))(x)&=(\tau\rho)_H(x)\\
&=
(\tau\rho)(x)\\
&=
\tau(\rho(x))\\
&=\tau(\rho_H(x))\\
&=\tau_H(\rho_H(x))\\
&=(\varphi(\tau))((\varphi(\rho))(x))\\
&=(\varphi(\tau)\varphi(\rho))(x)
\end{align}$$

for all $x\in \{1,\dots, n\}$ and all $\tau,\rho\in H$, so that

$$\varphi(\tau\rho)=\varphi(\tau)\varphi(\rho).\,\square$$

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer but I'm really confuse. The permutation (1, 5)(2, 3, 4)(6, 7) in $S_7$, maps 1 to 5. When I apply your function, 5 maps to 5, 2 maps to 3, 3 to 4, 4 to 2, 6 to 7 and 7 to 6. But now, 1 is empty, because in $S_7$ the image of 1 was 5, and same for 8. If I map 8 to itself for every permutation, the subgroup of $S_8$ has 6! elements and not 7! So, those are the real doubts: 1 (in $S_8$) should be go to the image of 5 (in $S_7$)? or should be go to 8? What if my permutation in $S_7$, 5 maps to 5? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well spotted, @JhonC! I have repaired the damage.

Answer (score 1):

For every $a\in A:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, set $B:=A\setminus\{a\}$. Then, $\operatorname{Stab}(a)\stackrel{\varphi}{\cong} S_B$ via $\sigma\mapsto\varphi(\sigma):=\sigma_{|B}$. In fact, firstly, $\sigma_{|B}\in S_B$ because $\sigma \in\operatorname {Stab}(a)$ (good definition). Moreover:

- injectivity: $\varphi(\sigma)=\varphi(\tau)\Longrightarrow \sigma_{|B}=\tau_{|B}\stackrel{\sigma(a)=a=\tau(a)}{\Longrightarrow}\sigma=\tau$;
- surjectivity: for any given $f\in S_B$, define $\sigma\in S_n$ by $(\sigma(a):=a) \wedge (\sigma_{|B}:=f)$; therefore, $\sigma\in\operatorname{Stab}(a)$ and $\varphi(\sigma)=f$;
- operation-preserving: for $b\in B$:
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  (\sigma\tau)(b) &= \sigma(\tau(b)) \\
  &\stackrel{b\in B}{=}\sigma(\tau_{|B}(b)) \\
  &\stackrel{\tau_{|B}(b)\in B}{=}\sigma_{|B}(\tau_{|B}(b)) \\
  &=(\sigma_{|B}\tau_{|B})(b) \\
  \end{alignat}
  On the other hand, $b\in B\Longrightarrow (\sigma\tau)(b)=(\sigma\tau)_{|B}(b)$. Therefore:
  $$\varphi(\sigma\tau)=(\sigma\tau)_{|B}=\sigma_{|B}\tau_{|B}=\varphi(\sigma)\varphi(\tau)$$
  Now, note that $|B|=n-1$, and hence $S_B\stackrel{\phi}{\cong} S_{n-1}$ for $\phi(f):=\mathscr gf\mathscr g^{-1}$, where $\mathscr g\colon B\longrightarrow \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ is any bijection. So, finally, for every $a\in A$:
  $$\operatorname{Stab}(a)\stackrel{\phi\varphi}{\cong} S_{n-1}$$
  Yours is just the particular case $n=8$ and $a=5$.